# Bedeutung von „Sauseschritt“

Tags: meaning

Dieses Wort erscheint in verschiedenen Liedern.

Ist es eine bestimmte Art zu gehen oder ein Tanz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sausen" ist etwas aus der Mode gekommen. Es bedeutet schnelle Bewegung, vom Wortgefühl vielleicht nicht so schnell wie rasen. Das Wort Sauseschritt ist eine Phrase, die in dem Zusammenhang gern verwendet wird. Hier hat sich das "sausen" noch gehalten. Oft wird sausen eher scherzhaft oder als verharmlosend noch verwendet, wie in "Ich sause mal los."